# In Java EE 6 / CDI what is the correct way to get a reference to the enclosing scope

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, java-ee-6

What is the correct way to get a reference to the enclosing scope in Java EE(6)/CDI? (Think for debugging.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you mean by the question, but if you're looking to get access to the currently active context in a given scope you can always

```
@Inject
private BeanManager beanManager;

...

    beanManager.getContext(MyScopeAnnotation.class);
```

If you're looking to discover what scope the current bean is in you can call

```
    beanManager.getBeans(MyClass.class).iterator().next().getScope();
```

Downside is that that approach won't let you know if someone overrides the scope at injection point.

Comment: Accepted as it answers the question. I thought there was one Dependent context for each Bean but it seems there is just one global Dependent context.

Comment: Dependent is a special scope, it essentially means no scope at all. Whenever you inject a dependent-scoped bean you get a new instance, and it's disposed of when the parent bean is discarded.

Comment: Thanks! What I really wanted to know was to find a simple way to find out which bean started the chain reaction that led to the instantiation of the bean that I'm currently logging so that I don't have to trace my way back every single time. I guess there is a simple way but my google skills fail me.